# Jquery .live triggering multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

My page contain a list of data. when I select and click on edit button , new form loads with using ajax with the populated data. When I click on the save button which is on form, it's triggering multiple times.

```
 $('#datasave').live('click' , function() {
     alert("here");
 });
```

I am getting the alert while clicking on the save button multiple times.
First load 2 time.
then if I repeat the above I am getting alert 3 times,
then if I repeat the above I am getting alert 4 times,

Comment: Have you tried using the `on` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try `delegate`

```
 $('body').delegate('#datasave','click' , function() {
     alert("here");
 });
```

Comment: Hi, 
I tried with delegate but its not working . We are getting same alert as before

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are binding "click" event to the button only once.

Check in your code,the fact that alerts number increases every time,
means you bind the event over and over again.

My suggestion, if you using "live" method, do it on document ready:

html:

```
<input type="button" id="datasave" value="Sava Data" />​
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
       $("#datasave").live(
           "click",
           function(){
              alert("Data Saved!");               
           }
       );            
    }
);​
```